# UDP client code throwing a very nonspecific exception

Tags: unity, c#, client-server, udp, unet

so I'm writing a UDP server and client on a couple of the machines in my virtual reality environment to allow (in this case) data from the location in the environment to trigger some air nozzles. The air nozzles I can control from the computer I have them plugged into, but I need to be able to control them from my machine running Unity. As far as I know, my server is functioning correctly, but I wrote a secondary listener script just to test it on the same machine and the error I'm getting is

> ```
> Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied.
> ```

not 100% what this means, as I'm fairly new to Unity and software coding. my Client code is as follows:

```
public class udplistener : MonoBehaviour {
  public IPEndPoint ipep; 
  public UdpClient udpListener; 
  public int port = 13722; 
  Thread udpThread;
  private Process process; 


  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
    ipep = new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Any, port);
    udpListener = new UdpClient(); 
    udpThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart(startProcess));
    udpThread.IsBackground = true;
    udpThread.Start ();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {
    try {
      while(true)
      { 
        byte[] recBytes = udpListener.Receive (ref ipep); 
        string data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (recBytes); 
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("Recieved data: " + data); 
      }
    }    
    catch (Exception e){
      UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Exception: " + e.ToString());
    } 
  }

  void startProcess(){
    process = new Process();

    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;

    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

    //process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory;
    //process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "";
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Starting client. Stand by...");

    //process.St
    process.Start();

    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Started client");
    // //Commented out for thread closing. Not used any more because of UDP client/server
    // while(true)
    // {
    //   ReadStdOut();
    // 
    //   if (programStopped)
    //   {
    //     return;
    //   }
    // }
  }
```

I'm really confused, because I lifted this code out of another portion of our software to create a "backdoor" into the dSPACE (the physical controller portion) machine so I wouldn't have to change a lot of serial communication that is already in place. What is the Exception referencing and what do I need to change?